# Configure Monolog from Yaml file

Tags: php, configuration, yaml, monolog

We are use `Monolog` for logging in our project. Judging by documentation there is no way to configure `Monolog` from config file, no matter `xml` or `yaml`. But as far as know there is a way to do this in Symfony. Unfortunately it highly depends on other Symfony components which we cannot afford to import to out project.

So, the question is: is there any way to configure `Monolog` from `yaml` file without using Symfony components?

Answer (score 2):

You might give [Monolog Cascade](https://github.com/theorchard/monolog-cascade) a try.

From the Readme:

> Monolog Cascade is a Monolog extension that allows you to set up and configure multiple loggers and handlers from a single config file.

Answer (score 2):

With Symfony, you might want to use [Monolog-Bundle](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle)
Detailed doc is here http://symfony.com/doc/current//logging.html

[Monolog-Cascade](https://github.com/theorchard/monolog-cascade) and Monolog-Bundle do essentially the same thing, Cascade being more agnostic. Nothing prevents you from using Cascade if you want even with Symfony.

I would add that Monolog Bundle uses a static mapping between configuration keys and corresponding classes for Handlers, Formatters, Processors; whereas Cascade resolves all this dynamically and does not need to be modified to support new Handlers, Formatters, Processors, etc.

[Disclaimer]: I'm the author of [Monolog-Cascade](https://github.com/theorchard/monolog-cascade)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting the XML to an array and using the `loadFromExtension()` as shown in this example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog_email.html - see the php tab.

Comment: `loadFromExtension` is a method of Symfony service container component, I cannot use it because we do not use Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

Use [yaml_parse_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.yaml-parse-file) to parse a `yaml` file to a php nested array structure. Than use the values in this array to configure monolog.

you could use a formatter to interpret log levels

```php
function monolog_level($value, $tag, $flags): \Monolog\Level {
    return \Monolog\Level::fromName($value);
}
```

and attach it to `!log_level`